# PHP Editing data from database per category data

Tags: php

My tabel database looks like this:

```
id | name         | Job       
-----------------------------
1  | Andrew       | Engineer  
2  | Fahmy        | Designer  
3  | Fitriani     | Animator  
4  | Karin        | Animator
```

i want to display data editing in my web, as you can see, there are two people with same job there, so if i do this:

```
$query="select * from tb_employees";
$show=mysql_query($query);
while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($show)){

$id= $data['id'];
echo" <tr>
      <td>$data[id_usulan]</td>
      <td>$data[name]</td>
      <td>$data[job]</td>
      <td><a href ='edit.php?id=$id'>Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href ='del.php?id=$id'>Delete</a></td>
      </tr>";
```

It will display all data in that table.

But what i want to do is to edit data per jobs, like this:

```
id | Job       | Option
---------------------------------------------
1  | Engineer  | Edit - Delete
2  | Designer  | Edit - Delete
3  | Animator  | Edit - Delete
```

(this is my editing interface, since my reputation is so small, i can't post image of my interface, sorry)

So if i Click edit in Animator, i want it to show per person with Animator job editing like this:

```
id | Name      | Option
---------------------------------------------
1  | Fitriani  | Edit - Delete
2  | Karin     | Edit - Delete
```

(this is my editing interface, since my reputation is so small, i can't post image of my interface, sorry)

So if i click edit in Karin, i want it to display Karin data editing interface, i use Mysql for database.

Sorry for my bad language.

Comment: $query="select job from tb_employees"; Why dont you run the query on this page and than run another query when some one click on the job?

Comment: my freind you just edited your post with out saying that any of the given solution is working or not. and if its not why its not working. if you use the comment section you can solve this you know

Comment: I just make some changes to my solution have look. rest the code going to remain remain same. and the isset($_get['id']) part going to come out side of while loop Thanks. let us know it work or not

Comment: sorry, since i can't speak, write, or undestand english very well, i got confused in how to response, and i don't quite understand what do you mean by "Why dont you run the query on this page and than run another query when some one click on the job", what do you mean by "run this query on this page"?, i was trying your solution right now, thanks for give me solution, i will ask again if it was working or not.. :)

Comment: Thanks and sorry. and let me know it work or not. dont worry it will be solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get data per job by the following query

```
$query="select * from tb_employees group by job ";
```

And when you will edit then run another query

```
$query="select * from tb_employees where job=$data[job] ";
```

Comment: i'll try it, thanks for give me solution, i'll tell you if it was working or not..

Answer (score 2):

Run a query like this

```
$query="select job from tb_employees";
```

Than run it like this

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id=$_get['id'];
    $sql="select name from tb_employees where job='$id'";
    $show=  mysql_query($sql);

    while($data=  mysql_fetch_array($show));
    echo $data['name'].'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: job='$id,  id is formatted like this "1,2,3" while job is formatted like this "Animator, designer, engineer", it can't show the data because job and id is different kind.

Comment: id does not matter how the id, is formatted. or job is formatted. if you dont tell us the error impossible to solved. and Rest assured it does not matter how to format your think. just tell me the error i am here for 15 minute. If you can explain we will get this thing done

Comment: sorry , my problem solved already, thank you very much for answering.. :)